# go import tg-bot-api

Tags: golang, telegram-bot, telegram, импорт

```golang
package main
import (
  "telegram-bot-api-master"
  "log"
)
```

При импорте этих библиотек выводит ошибку: `non-standard import "github.com/technoweenie/multipartstreamer" in standard package "telegram-bot-api-master"`, GOPATH и остальные стоят нормально, не пойму в чем проблема, качал через go get, качается в рабочую папку, с подключаемой библиотекой не взаимодействует.

GOPATH: /home/pc

GOROOT: /usr/lib/go-1.6 (библиотека - /usr/lib/go-1.6/src/telegram-bot-api-master/)

Answer (score 2):

Если ваш `GOPATH = /home/pc`

То `go get` должен загружать вашу библиотеку сюда `/home/pc/src/github.com/go-telegram-bot-api/telegram-bot-api`

И импортировать нужно как обычно

```golang
import "github.com/go-telegram-bot-api/telegram-bot-api"
```

Содержимое `/usr/lib/go-1.6` лучше вообще не трогать.

Поскольку вы сами скопировали в `/usr/lib/go-1.6/src/` где живут только стандартные библиотеки. Го думает что это стандартная библиотека, вот и жалуется.

И почему у ваш 1.6? Последняя версия 1.11.